# Is it possible for to hide a link of a website if it's visited from a user outside a network?

Tags: php, system

It's hard to explain but we have this proposed system for a hospital and we are on the phase of coding it but the problem is we can't visualize it since the system needs to be internet-based. We have 3 modules which are the billing, employee management, and clinical system. Those 3 modules are obviously only accessible by the workers inside the hospital. But what we did was we linked those 3 modules in the website itself. So any user can see that link which they have no business on but they still see it. 
How can avoid that?

Comment: Is there a signin process for these pages?

Comment: @DWolf Yes. So it would be secure. But i still want it to be hidden by just regular users cause there is no point on showing those when its an outside user.

Comment: well in that case you should have a check if there is a session variable for user, to set the visibility of the link as true, if the session variable !is_set then you can set the visibility to false.   But i do like Oswalds answer best.

Answer (score 2):

Use the IP address of the client to determine whether the user is allowed to see the links.

In PHP, the IP address of the client can usually be found in [`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). However, if the web server is behind a reverse proxy, all requests come from the reverse proxy. In that case, consult the documentation of the reverse proxy about which HTTP headers it sends to notify the server about the actual IP address of the client.

The hospital probably has a [CIDR](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing)-block of IP addresses, so you can test whether the client is within this block without actually searching for an IP address in a list.

If the hospital provides WLAN for patients and guests, those IP adresses should probably excluded.

Comment: That's what i thought too. So it is possible? So i should get the IP address of the hospital and then.. what? We use PHP. How can we restrict users from seeing those link other than the IP of the hospital?

Comment: [link](http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10327697-how-to-get-client-s-IP-address-in-PHP) heres a link that provides information about his answer

Comment: and i say oswald gets the answer